# Create event recurring of calendar

Tags: android

I use code to create event recurring of calendar:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 26);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5 - 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Event Title 1");
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Event Desc");
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Event Location");
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, calendar.getTimeInMillis());
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;WKST=SU");
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, 1);   // 0 for false, 1 for     true
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.STATUS, CalendarContract.Events.STATUS_CONFIRMED);
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DURATION, "P3600S");
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE,  calendar.getTimeZone().getID());
Uri url =     getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, event);
```

When I delete a event in app default calendar, dialog delete only show 1 option delete.

[image]

But, when I create event recurring in app default calendar, dialog delete show 2 option delete.

[image]

Why difference between create event of my code and create event of app default calendar?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error.

Default calendar will create new event with one-time repeation (when delete event: show 1 option delete). If you choose Repeation is daily it will create the set of event (when delete event: show 2 option delete). If you want to create ontime event you can remove line:

```
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;WKST=SU");
```

in your code.

You will see one option when delete it.